# Need to position 3 anchor links in the legend tag

Tags: html, anchor

I want to position 3 anchor tags at the far right inside a legend tag. This is how i am doing it:

```
 <legend>Search criteria to select message recipients                 
                <small>
                <a href="Delete.jsp" id="Delete1" style=" text-decoration:none" class="pull-right"   >Delete</a>
                <a href="edit.jsp" id="Edit1" style="text-decoration:none" class="pull-right"   >Edit</a>
                <a href="message0.jsp" id="Add1" style=" text-decoration:none" class="pull-right"   >Add </a>
                </small>
                </legend>
```

The problem is that there is no space inbetween the three tags that is they are appearing as(AddEditDelete) but I want them to appear as (Add Edit Delete)

Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways i did it using css

defined a class

.padded{
padding-left: 1em;

}

and included it in each of the  tags.